# When killing the Ambush with the Assassin, does the player gain one token?

Tags: oriflamme

In the game Oriflamme, when the Assassin kills the Ambush, does the owner of the Assassin gain a token ?

The rules state that the Archer and Soldier do gain a token in this use case, however it is not specified for the Assassin...